# How to insert data into two table related by foreign key relation in sql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table `goals`, `goalscore`.

```
goals table fields(GoalId,UserId,GoalName,StartDate,EndDate).
```

`GoalId` is the **primary key(auto increment)**.

In `goalscore` table

`(GoalScoreId, GoalId, GoalExpected,GoalAchieve, Score)`

```
 GoalScoreId(primarykey(auto increment)) GoalId(foreign Key from goals)
```

Now I want to insert data from the same form to both the table. 
First goals table and from that table I want to get GoalId and according to that, need to insert related data of the same goal to `goalscore` table.

Sometimes am using for loop to insert multiple data to the table. So last insert id I can't take. Is there any option.

Please help me to find the solution.

code is given

```
public function AddNewGoal(){
$userid=$this->session->userdata['loggedin']['userId'];

$Cdate=date('Y-m-d');
$Ldate=date('Y-m-d');
$date = $this->input->post('sdate');
//$freq = $this->input->post('frequency');
$freq= 1;
$kpiId= $this->input->post('kpiname');
$goal = $this->input->post('Goal');
$goaltype = $this->input->post('goaltype');
$targetscore = $this->input->post('target');

$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('12/31'));
//echo $yearEnd; exit();


$mnth= date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
$m = 12- $mnth;
$q = 12-$mnth;

If($freq==1){
    $i=1;
    While ($i<= $m)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO goals
        (UserId,KPITTemplateItemId,GoalTypeId,GoalStatusId,GoalDesc,StartDate,EndDate,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,LastModifiedOn,LastModifiedBy)
        VALUES
        (180,1,1,4,"goal","'.$date.'","'.$date.'","'.$date.'","'.$userid.'","'.$date.'","'.$userid.'")');
        $i++;



    }



}
else if($freq==2){



}
else if($freq==3){



}
else if($freq==4){




}
else if($freq==5){

    $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO goals
        (UserId,KPITTemplateItemId,GoalTypeId,GoalStatusId,GoalDesc,StartDate,EndDate,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,LastModifiedOn,LastModifiedBy)
        VALUES
        (180,1,1,4,"goal","'.$date.'","'.$date.'","'.$date.'","'.$userid.'","'.$date.'","'.$userid.'")');


}

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer first? This is basic stuff that has been answered many times. Please search first then try again.

Comment: where is your code ???
these all are basic stuff , if you try something share here

Comment: i tried. but if am inserting single data , i can use last inserted id. but in my condition am inserting same data multiple time based on goal frequency

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function last_inserted_id for this purpose in mysql.